# prettyphoto undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, prettyphoto

I'm attempting to install prettyPhoto lightbox on my site and I keep getting them same error. The following code in the console generates this error

```
"undefined is not a function"

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
      });
    </script>
```

*Line 18*

I've tried it in the footer and the head, both cause the same problem and the lightbox doesn't load.

Here's the files in my head tag...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My site is www.jessicadraws.com

Any ideas?

Dave.

Comment: btw, did you include prettyPhoto js ..?

Comment: Seems like it can't find the prettyPhoto.js file, then the prettyPhoto() function is undefined. Where are you including the prettyPhoto script?

Comment: It's included in the head tag
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page loads 3 versions of jQuery. This is likely causing issues with other plugins. Pretty Photo is loading fine - it's just loading onto jQuery 1.9

I can see this by running this in the devtools:

```
var jquery162 = $.noConflict(true);
> undefined
$.fn.jquery
> "1.9.0"
$.prettyPhoto
> Object {version: "3.1.5"}
```

To fix this won't be simple unfortunately, you'll need to decide which version of jQuery you are using and stop loading the rest.

For reference in `<head>` you are loading:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

PrettyPhoto is loaded just after these, in the head.

In your `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great that fixed it thank you but it's broken my header menu. Is there any way around this? Looks like the header menu needs <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I would advise that you use the lowest version of jQuery you are already loading, and then try to work your way up.

Comment: No problem - welcome to StackOverflow. If you found this helpful please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark so others know it helped you.